# nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "passenger_root" directive

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger, rubber, ruby-2.1

I'm trying to set up for the first time with Rubber onto EC2 (complete_passenger_nginx_postgresql). I changed a bunch of settings in the config files to make it work with a different AMI (Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS - ami-a73264ce (64-bit)), Ruby 2.1.0, Passenger 4.0.29, and Nginx 1.4.4.
I almost got it to work, but it failed when starting Nginx with the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "passenger_root" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:45
```

rubber-passenger_nginx.yml has the following code for "passenger_root":

```
passenger_lib: "#{passenger_root}/ext/nginx"
```

Any idea what I should change to make it work?

Comment: Please include your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf: line 45

Comment: Here:
`/usr/local/rubies/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.29;` and here is line 44 to 46: `passenger_root /usr/local/rubies/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/passenger-4.0.29
/usr/local/rubies/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.29;
        passenger_ruby /usr/local/rubies/2.1.0/bin/ruby;`

Answer (score 16):

In My case, I have missed to mention **`;`** at the end of the root directory declaration

**Error:**

```
root "/directory/with double quotes/will work"
```

**Solution:**

```
root "/directory/with double quotes/will work";
```

Comment: lifesaver lmfao

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file.

Change the lines:

```
passenger_root /usr/local/rubies/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static‌​/passenger-4.0.29
/usr/local/rubies/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.29;
passenger_ruby /usr/local/rubies/2.1.0/bin/ruby;
```

into:

```
passenger_root /usr/local/rubies/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.29;
passenger_ruby /usr/local/rubies/2.1.0/bin/ruby;
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, indeed you are right, but the problem is a little more complicated. In fact, in file "rubber-passenger_nginx.yml" the passenger root is extrapolated with the following string: `passenger_root: "#{`bash -l -c 'find #{ruby_path} -name passenger-#{passenger_version}'`.strip}"` so I replaced that with the hard coded path. Not an ideal solution, but that worked. I also had other issues later that needed to be solved and I'm still not done. Since it's a lot to write, I will post a link to a blog post where I share my misery and solutions, hopefully :) Thank you.

Comment: @BenKass I know this is way after the fact, but I was able to resolve this by adding a simple grep to the calculation of the passenger root directory so that it only returns the gem path and not the wrapped extension path. passenger_root: "#{`bash -l -c 'find #{ruby_path} -name passenger-#{passenger_version} | grep \\'gems/passenger\\''`.strip}"